# ImageView - display new Image and reset after 1 sec - onClick

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an **ImageView** that is initially set to show (say) a.png. Now, when I click on it - I need it to change its image resource to (say) b.png and then in 1000 ms revert back to a.png.

```
  @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0)
 {
    ImageView iView = (ImageView) arg0;
    iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bpng);
    iView.invalidate();

    Handler delayHandler = new Handler();
    delayHandler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.apng);
 }
```

From what I have read around on the SO Questions - the **invalidate** method (I also tried **postInvalidate**) should put in a request to update the View. However I noticed that the above code never really shows the imageView with b.png.

Any suggestions on how I can get this done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to move the line `iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.apng);` to within the run() method.

currently, your `run()` method is waiting for a second, and then doing nothing. So the method flow goes:

```
setImage <- b.png

postDelayed

setImage <- a.png

1000ms later

run finished
```